# Error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Tags: php, mysql

```
include_once 'include/connect_db.php';
$query="SELECT tm FROM schedule WHERE val='BT009';";
$result=ejecutar_query($query);

$rows = array();

if ($result && mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    foreach ($result as $row):
        $rows[] = $row['tm'];
        echo $row['tm'];       
    endforeach;
}
```

I'm sure SQL query should return 1 entry. However, echo outputs 'Array'. The error message is: Invalid argument supplied for foreach().

Comment: What is `ejecutar_query`. It sounds like something dirty :D

Comment: This function ejecutes query. It works fine with no doubts.

Comment: In that case you may want to change to `execute_query` :)

Comment: @petra in English, that's "execute" ;-)

Comment: @petra he only needs to do that if he's sharing the code.

Comment: Which part of the error message don't you understand? And can you please explain why on earth that code *should* work at all? It looks totally out of order.

Comment: @Matt Looks like he just shared his code already :)

Comment: I had to connect to DB. That was missing. Hope that 'ejecutar' does not influence the result:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your for loop:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row['ETA'];
    echo $row['ETA'];
}
print_r($rows); // To double check
```

Answer (score 2):

The error tells you everything: `$result` is not, in fact, an array (or at least not a populated array).

You can't `echo` an array. Perform a `var_dump()` or `print_r` on it.

Also, you set `$rows = array();` just prior to looping through it. WTF, dude?

You're essentially saying "for each index of this empty array...do stuff."

Instead try:

```
if (is_array($result) && count($result)) { ... }
```

If `$result` is a resultset from a mysql query and you want to loop through *that*, try this:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

**Please note:** You should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: please stop linking to that horrible "SO article"

Comment: @tereško when people stop using deprecated functions, I'll stop trying to correct them.

Comment: @tereško if you don't like it, suggest an alternative. Be a part of the community.

Comment: @tereško A comment that equates to "you suck" is not constructive. Explaining *why* a person sucks and how that person can stop sucking is. See the difference?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/apis-php-mysqlinfo.api.choosing.html

Comment: @tereško I updated my link to something else. Is *that* to your satisfaction?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming $result is a MySQL result set, in which case you do not just iterate over it, you would need to use some method to turn the result set to an array like:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row['tm'];
    echo $row['tm'];
}
```